# Adding text on number counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make counter animation but when i write a text it says NaN when i write only numbers it works perfectly

**HTML**

```
<div class="counter-value" data-count="300">300</div>
      <div class="counter-value" data-count="400">100</div>
      <div class="counter-value" data-count="1500">200</div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {

  var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
    $('.counter-value').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      $({
        countNum: $this.text()
      }).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        },

        {

          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function () {
            $this.text(this.countNum);

          }

        });
    });
    a = 1;
  }

});
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
300+sometext
400+sometext
1500+sometext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do two things to handle it. Replace the following functions with the following code:

```js
step: function() {
  $this.text(Math.floor(parseInt(this.countNum, 10)));
},
complete: function() {
  $this.text(this.countNum + " some text...");
}
```

Comment: your method works but it shows this result: 300 test
400 test
1500 test  is there any ways that i can make different text for different data-count

Comment: @IbrahimS.Gerbiqi You can do by using another `data-text="some text"` and appending it with `this.countNum +  $this.data("text")`...